# How can I report a bug in Magento Enterprise?

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.13, bug

I've discovered a bug with Website Restrictions and Onepage Checkout in Magento Enterprise 1.13.  Though I'm developing a work-around, I'd like to also submit a bug ticket.

When trying to [report a bug](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/report/), the available versions are limited to Community Edition.  What is the correct process for reporting a bug in Enterprise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best means is to submit a support ticket when logged into your account on magentocommerce.com

The purpose of EE is that it is an SLA backed product; submit a support request so they will fix it on your behalf.

Be sure to provide exact replication steps.

Comment: Are Enterprise customers still limited to N number of support requests a year?  If so is there a separate process for reporting bugs that you've handled yourself, but would like to see fixed in future versions?

Comment: Magento EE customers can submit an unlimited amount of support requests AFAIK. All reporting happens via the same form ;)

Comment: Thanks guys.  Submitting the support request provided a much cleaner solution than I'd come up with, and will hopefully ensure it's fixed in future patches.